# Download attachments from outlook and store them in Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have written a Java code using Java Mail API which downloads attachments from a specified mailbox.I want to store these attachments to some bucket in Google Cloud Storage.How can I do that using Google Cloud Dataflow?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, a task like this can be accomplished in Dataflow by having a batch pipeline that interacts with [Custom Sources and Sinks](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io). Keep in mind that your source should support splitting into multiple parts, in order to benefit from parallel execution in the cloud.